# PHP need to count the number of same characters in a sequence in a string

Tags: php

I am using php to merge text server side in an rtf format file.
My fields are identified by a sequence of tildes in different parts of the file.
Each sequence is a different length.
In order to use `substr_replace` to replace the field with the merge material I need to count the length of the sequence of tildes.
I can find the first tilde without a problem using:

```
$firsttilde=strpos($filedata,'~',$currentposinfile);
```

Where (in this code) `$filedata` is a string containing the file contents and `$currentposinfile` is my start point for the search.
My problem is that I cannot find a function which can count the number of same characters in a sequence.

From the first tilde that part of `$filedata` I am looking at looks like this (in other words a sequence of tildes):

> '~~~~~~~~~~'

I have tried `strrpos` to find the last tilde, but that is finding my fields containing tildes in a later part of `$filedata`.
All I want to do is count the number of tildes from the position that I am aware of in the string, but I cannot find any function to do this.
There must be one though.

Comment: So the difference between the position of the first tilde and the position from the first non-tilde character from that point?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all` in combination with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag. This will save the offset at which the string was found in the matches variable, allowing you to both find the string and it's offset.

```
$matches = Array();
preg_match_all( '/~+/', $input, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

foreach( $matches[0] as $k => $v ) {
  $length = strlen( $v[0] );
  echo "Found a string \"{$v[0]}\" beginning at {$v[1]} with length {$length}<br>";
}
```

For the example text below

```
$input = <<<TEXT
this is
~~~~~~~~

quite something
~~~~
TEXT;
```

the output would be:

```
Found a string "~~~~~~~~" beginning at 8 with length 8
Found a string "~~~~" beginning at 34 with length 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a for iteration to examine the chars in the text.
It's an alternative to the preg_match() solutions, which are more compact.

```
<?php

$text = <<<'TEXT'
abc
~~~
def
~~~~~~
123
~~~~~~~~~~
TEXT;

//$currentposinfile = 0;
//$firsttilde = strpos($text,'~',$currentposinfile);
//$text = substr($text, $firsttilde);

$sequenceStarted = false;
$sequenceLength = 0;

$textLength = strlen($text);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $textLength; $i++) {
    $char = $text[$i]; 

    //echo 'Char ' . $char . '  at ' . $i . PHP_EOL;

    if($char === '~') {

        // found start of a sequence
        if($sequenceStarted === false) {
           $sequenceLength++;      
           $sequenceStarted = true;      
           $sequenceStartPosition = $i;
        } 

        // it's a char in sequence               
        continue;
    }

    // found first char out of sequence
    if($char !== '~' && $sequenceStarted === true) {
         $sequenceStarted = false;
         $sequenceEndPostion = $i - 1;
         $sequenceLength = $i - $sequenceStartPosition;

         echo 'Found a sequence of length: ' .  $sequenceLength . ' starting at '.$sequenceStartPosition.' ending at ' . $sequenceEndPostion . '.' . PHP_EOL;

         #break;

         $sequenceLength = 0; $sequenceEndPostion = 0;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Found a sequence of length: 3 starting at 5 ending at 7.
Found a sequence of length: 6 starting at 15 ending at 20.
Found a sequence of length: 10 starting at 28 ending at 37.
```

---

If you already have the sequence chunks, you might simply use [count_chars()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.count-chars.php).

```
<?php

$text = 'ABC~~~123';

$data = count_chars($text, 1);

echo 'The string "'. $text .'" contains the char "~" '. $data[126] . ' times.';
```

$data[126] = uses the ASCII code 126 for ~

Result: The string "ABC~~~123" contains the char "~" 3 times.

Demo: https://eval.in/204882

Answer (score 0):

The following function will loop through the string and return an array of matches:

```
function findSequences($str)
{
    $ret = array();
    $len = strlen($str);
    $count = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i <= $len; $i ++)
    {
        $char = @$str[$i] ?: null;

        if($char == '~')
        {
            $count ++;
        }
        elseif($count > 0)
        {
            // Found end of sequence
            $ret[] = array(
                'start' => $i - $count,
                'end' => $i - 1,
                'len' => $count
            );

            $count = 0;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Example usage:

```
print_r(findSequences('~ABC~~~123~~'));
```

Will output a array with details of the found matches:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 0
            [end] => 0
            [len] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 4
            [end] => 6
            [len] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 10
            [end] => 11
            [len] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your answers.
They encouraged me to try a bit harder to find a simple solution.

I came up with this:-

```
$lasttilde=$firsttilde;
while ($filedata[$lasttilde]=='~') { $lasttilde++; }
```

Then the number of tildes in that particular part of `$filedata` is the difference between `$lasttilde` and `$firsttilde`